# Insert comma separated data in external table in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, external-tables

```
create external table transaction_usa_canada
(
tran_id int,
acct_id int,
tran_date string,
amount double,
description string,
branch_code string,
product string,
tran_state string,
tran_city string,
speendby string,
tran_zip int,
source_table string
)
row format delimited
stored as textfile
location '/user/DSNew18/Bank_DS18/tran_usa_canada';




INSERT INTO TABLE myproject.transaction_usa_canada 
SELECT tran_id, acct_id, tran_date, amount, description, branch_code,'', tran_state, tran_city, speendby, tran_zip, 'usa' AS source_table FROM transaction_usanew18
UNION ALL
SELECT tran_id, acct_id, tran_date, amount, description, branch_code,'', tran_state, tran_city, speendby, tran_zip, 'canada' AS source_table FROM transaction_canadanew18;
```

Above is my query to insert into an external table in hive by combining 2 other external tables. Everything runs fine. Just the problem is that the data that is getting stored in the table is not comma separated. What changes I should make in order to get data in a comma seperated format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in create table

```
CREATE Table table(
 ....
)
row format delimited    
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’
```

Comment: where to add in the following query.. I tried that... giving error...

INSERT INTO TABLE myproject.transaction_usa_canada 
SELECT tran_id, acct_id, tran_date, amount, description, branch_code,'', tran_state, tran_city, speendby, tran_zip, 'usa' AS source_table FROM transaction_usanew18
UNION ALL
SELECT tran_id, acct_id, tran_date, amount, description, branch_code,'', tran_state, tran_city, speendby, tran_zip, 'canada' AS source_table FROM transaction_canadanew18;

Comment: No i mean After  INSERT INTO TABLE myproject.transaction_usa_canada .? Or at the end.?

Comment: You have to add it in CREATE Table statement

Comment: ok.. Thanks.I am trying to alter the external table but its giving me an error. How can I alter the external table.?

Comment: drop external table and then again create the table

Comment: Worked like a charm.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
create external table transaction_usa_canada
(
tran_id int,
acct_id int,
tran_date string,
amount double,
description string,
branch_code string,
product string,
tran_state string,
tran_city string,
speendby string,
tran_zip int,
source_table string
)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location '/user/DSNew18/Bank_DS18/tran_usa_canada';




INSERT INTO TABLE myproject.transaction_usa_canada 
SELECT tran_id, acct_id, tran_date, amount, description, branch_code,'', tran_state, tran_city, speendby, tran_zip, 'usa' AS source_table FROM transaction_usanew18
UNION ALL
SELECT tran_id, acct_id, tran_date, amount, description, branch_code,'', tran_state, tran_city, speendby, tran_zip, 'canada' AS source_table FROM transaction_canadanew18;
```

**Use the above code to get the data as comma seperated.**